# when vpn is connected intenet is not accessible

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I need vpn to access certain lan. The problem is - when I connect to vpn intenet stop working. But I need to have access to lan and intenet at the same time.
When VPN is connected and I try tracert, I receive "The network is unreachable" message.

Sorry about Russian language below, this is copy-pasted from console:

```
C:\Users\Oleg>tracert 173.194.69.102

Трассировка маршрута к bk-in-f102.1e100.net [173.194.69.102]
с максимальным числом прыжков 30:

  1     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  2  1.1.1.1  сообщает: Заданная сеть недоступна.

Трассировка завершена.
```

or after Google Translate:

```
C:\Users\Oleg>tracert 173.194.69.102

Tracing route to bk-in-f102.1e100.net [173.194.69.102]
with a maximum of 30 hops:

   1 *** timed out a request.
   1.1.1.1 two reports: The specified network is unavailable.

Trace complete.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you run the VPN server? What software does the server run? it may be that the server only allows LAN access and blocks internet.

Comment: @tapped-out i run standart windows vpn access client

Comment: that's the client software. what vpn server software does the server (the thing you connect to) run?

Comment: @tapped-out I don't know. Is it important? I can ask owners of the server

Comment: @tapped-out I want to access intenet without using VPN Server. Why can't I go to internet using my regular connection ignoring the fact that I'm also connected to vpn. I can open two tabs in browser and go to yahoo in one and google in another. As yahoo can not prohibit me to go to google I expect that vpn server can not prohibit me to go to internet.

Comment: its important, as the server can be configured to only allow intranet (LAN) access (i.e. not internet). when you're connected to the vpn, ALL traffic goes through the VPN, and if the vpn is not configured to let internet traffic through, it will fail.

Comment: @tapped-out why all traffic goes thru vpn? is it technology restriction?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2963/discussion-between-javapowered-and-tapped-out)

Answer (score 5):

This was discussed in chat, but for future reference:

1. Right-click on the VPN and select "Properties"
2. Select the "Networking" tab
3. Select "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)"
4. Click the "Advanced..." Button
5. Uncheck "Use default gateway on remote network"
6. Click OK, OK, OK...

This is called a "split tunnel", where not all of the traffic is routed through the VPN. Traffic intended for the remote network goes through the VPN, but normal traffic goes through the normal connection.

The downside is that UDP MULTICAST packets won't be received from the remote network by the client.

Comment: By some reason I'm not able to receive Udp Multicast packets. I suspect that probably igmp "join group" request is routed to internet instead of routing to lan and so I can not join group. But i'm not sure about that