# in wireshark how to know if packet was send to vpn or to internet?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, udp

Thanks to my previous question [when vpn is connected intenet is not accessible](https://superuser.com/questions/407336/when-vpn-is-connected-intenet-is-not-accessible) I have configured VPN connection so I can use internet at the same time. Right now I write this post and I'm connected to VPN. I do see lan computer 1.1.1.30 and at the same time I see google.com:

```
C:\Users\Oleg>ping 1.1.1.30

Обмен пакетами с 1.1.1.30 по с 32 байтами данных:
Ответ от 1.1.1.30: число байт=32 время=22мс TTL=255

Статистика Ping для 1.1.1.30:
    Пакетов: отправлено = 1, получено = 1, потеряно = 0
    (0% потерь)
Приблизительное время приема-передачи в мс:
    Минимальное = 22мсек, Максимальное = 22 мсек, Среднее = 22 мсек
Control-C
^C
C:\Users\Oleg>ping google.com

Обмен пакетами с google.com [173.194.69.138] с 32 байтами данных:
Ответ от 173.194.69.138: число байт=32 время=50мс TTL=44
```

The problem is that I do not receive UDP Multicast packets from lan. I think this is probably because "join group" request was sent to internet instead of sending to lan via vpn. I copy paste below "igmp join group request" packet but I don't know how can I know if it was sent to "right party". I.e. to VPN, not to internet?

```
0000  01 00 5e 00 00 16 00 16  eb 2a 11 ce 08 00 46 00   ..^..... .*....F.
0010  00 2c 32 a9 00 00 01 02  50 60 c0 a8 01 04 e0 00   .,2..... P`......
0020  00 16 94 04 00 00 22 00  05 fc 00 00 00 01 05 00   ......". ........
0030  00 01 ef c0 6f 01 ac 14  c8 2a                     ....o... .*
```

**upd**

and this is correct packet:

```
0000  00 23 54 b5 6a a0 00 16  eb 2a 11 ce 08 00 45 00   .#T.j... .*....E.
0010  00 50 3c fc 00 00 80 2f  4d 57 c0 a8 01 04 c2 54   .P<..../ MW.....T
0020  2c 2b 30 01 88 0b 00 30  db 03 00 00 02 12 ff 03   ,+0....0 ........
0030  00 21 46 00 00 2c 02 03  00 00 01 02 40 a6 01 01   .!F..,.. ....@...
0040  01 0c e0 00 00 16 94 04  00 00 22 00 05 fc 00 00   ........ ..".....
0050  00 01 05 00 00 01 ef c0  6f 01 ac 14 c8 2a         ........ o....*
```

When internet works "join group request" is sent from wrong ip 192.168.1.4 - this is ip of my lan, not vpn lan

When internet doesn't work "joing group request" is setn from correct ip 1.1.1.12.

So the question is how to make internet work and at the same time keep udp multicast to use vpn lan...

Comment: Why are you using the IP address `1.1.1.12`?  That is not in the IANA private network ranges (`10.0.0.0` – `10.255.255.255`, `172.16.0.0` – `172.31.255.255`, and `192.168.0.0` – `192.168.255.255`).

Comment: @paradroid vpn owners use this network, i don't know why

Comment: These people are wrong to do so.  I use various VPN systems and I have never seen this.  There are millions of addresses you can use within the proper private network ranges.

Comment: @paradroid question is not about if folks right or wrong. I can't change that. the question is why my configuration doesn't work. why when I subscribe to udp multicast wrong source ip is used...